# Android Java : How to subtract two times?

Tags: java, android, timer, subtraction

I  use some kind of stopwatch in my project and I have

```
start time ex: 18:40:10 h
stop time  ex: 19:05:15 h
```

I need a result from those two values like `final time = stop - start`

I found some examples but they all are very confusing .

Is there any simple solution ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have strings you need to parse them into a java.util.Date using java.text.SimpleDateFormat. Something like:

```
        java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        java.util.Date date1 = df.parse("18:40:10");
        java.util.Date date2 = df.parse("19:05:15");
        long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```

Here diff is the number of milliseconds elapsed between 18:40:10 and 19:05:15.

EDIT 1:

Found a method online for this (at http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2001/jw-0330-time.html?page=2):

```
  int timeInSeconds = diff / 1000;
  int hours, minutes, seconds;
  hours = timeInSeconds / 3600;
  timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds - (hours * 3600);
  minutes = timeInSeconds / 60;
  timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds - (minutes * 60);
  seconds = timeInSeconds;
```

EDIT 2:

If you want it as a string (this is a sloppy way, but it works):

```
String diffTime = (hours<10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds) + " h";
```

EDIT 3:

If you want the milliseconds just do this

```
long timeMS = diff % 1000;
```

You can then divide that by 1000 to get the fractional part of your seconds.

Comment: Aham   i saw samples like that  but  again I need  result as 01:10.34 h  ,  here  I get  result in millisecond  and  need more mathematics to get wished result ,  is there simplest solution  ?

Comment: How are you going to get milliseconds in your result if your time is only recording hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: quadelirus Thanks a lot I get what  I  want :)  I  use :
 start= System.currentTimeMillis();

but I do some DateFormating to get only hours :)  Now  I  get  what I need ,  thank's  again ..

Comment: I was done  some  string  formating ,  but  as I tested those line it  is  better solution :) Thanks one more time quadelirus.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you are using [java.util.Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

```
long totalTime = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
```

The result will be the total time in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks Thierry I completed a task :)

Answer (score 1):

I am providing the modern answer.

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss 'h'");

    String startTimeString = "18:40:10 h";
    String stopTimeString = "19:05:15 h";

    LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse(startTimeString, timeFormatter);
    LocalTime stopTime = LocalTime.parse(stopTimeString, timeFormatter);

    if (stopTime.isBefore(startTime)) {
        System.out.println("Stop time must not be before start time");
    } else {
        Duration difference = Duration.between(startTime, stopTime);

        long hours = difference.toHours();
        difference = difference.minusHours(hours);
        long minutes = difference.toMinutes();
        difference = difference.minusMinutes(minutes);
        long seconds = difference.getSeconds();

        System.out.format("%d hours %d minutes %d seconds%n", hours, minutes, seconds);
    }
```

Output from this example is:

> 0 hours 25 minutes 5 seconds

The other answers were good answers in 2010. Today avoid the classes `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is so much nicer to work with.

### But doesn’t it require API level 26?

No, using java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer it will help you a lot

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53890863/8193199)

In this answer, you will find subtract to two times discarding the day and month and year.

it gives you the number of minutes you will spend until you reach the second Time value.

Answer (score 0):

Today, with newer Java (no idea, at what Android version this works):

```
Instant before = Instant.now();
// do stuff

Duration.between(before, Instant.now()).getSeconds()
```

The clumsy java ways from olden days are now gone.